# Meditation in day to day life

Tags: vipassana

I lost my interest in things,I just do only day to day life.Is it depression?This  happened some months  back. I think it is related to my vipassana meditation. Now in meditation saw the sadness and negative  thoughts comes ,stays and goes. But only see the sadness not happiness. So what shall I do to pass this state?

Comment: Meditation is good, but also don't forget your daily outdoor physical exercises. Sometimes, the fix is as simple as getting out to the open air and start some cardio workout like running, jogging, biking, etc. Give it a try if you haven't...

Comment: I suspect this is one of the dangers of vipassana when it is the only practice.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should augment your vipassana with other meditations intended to cultivate virtuous minds. I would suggest meditations on the four immeasurables : https://thubtenchodron.org/2002/11/love-compassion-equaminity-joy/

Answer (score 0):

Respected Buddhika,

**I lost my interest in things,I just do only day to day life.Is it depression?**
It's something that only your friends/near-by-ones can tell.
Although, there is a point in life, when almost everyone looses interest-- for some it remains temporary, for some it stays for merely a fraction of seconds, for some it can bring disasters by persisting.
Better, to consult with psychologist and/or your physical teacher(if any).

**Now in meditation saw the sadness and negative thoughts comes ,stays and goes. But only see the sadness not happiness. So what shall I do to pass this state?**

This in itself is a self-contradictory view. If it comes, stays(?) and goes, i.e. it is already passing-by then why do you want to do something to `let this state pass`?

It seems, when it `stays` then your intention is that of `you wanna see happiness` or `where is happiness type of quest`. This ultimately leading a conflicting state to persist in your body, **desiring and craving for something(happiness)**. It leads you to subconsciously rejects/neglects the already happy moments or happiness in life.

Old-Geezer's advice is:: daughter, you are worrying too much.

Meditator's advice:: you have to work-up on your intentions. Some physical exercise and fresh-air may help by increasing circulation of blood&oxygen & hence rejecting negative thoughts. Try to laugh by watching some laugh-tv-series, playing games(outdoor games).
Remember, it's not mind always that affects body in bad/good manner rather sometimes body can also help in stabilizing oe destabilizing mind.

Be happpy.